# I'm seeking the canonical, geo-universal link for downloading the latest Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

I have a "download the latest browser" page that will appear to many users worldwide, but the only links I can find for downloading IE *either* point to a specific local (eg, en-US) OR a specific version # (eg, IE9).  Does anyone know if there's a canonical, locale-generic landing page for IE?

I will keep looking and update if I find the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/internetexplorer will redirect the user to the latest version. In fact this was the first link that popped up when Googling "download ie" (even on a Mac, what a shame).

Comment: Thanks!  Maybe I am a class A moron, but I've been googling for 20 minutes and only saw /IE9 or /us-en/etc.